# In a visual studio setup project, how do I prevent a conditional custom action to run?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-setup-proje

I have a very simple Visual Studio 2010 setup project.
In this project I have a simple custom action, running a thirdy part executable. Nothing really complicated so far.
Now, I want to add a parameter, so, when running the installer, I have the option to skip this custom action.
Let's say, for example, that I want to run my installer using a switch, at command prompt. Something like this

my-msi-name.msi /NOACTION

What I want to achieve is to skip the custom action if this "/NOACTION" is added as a switch, else run it.
Is this a possible option? I can't find any answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Late reply, but:

a) The syntax for running an MSI-based install is msiexec /I

b) If you do a msiexec /I  RUNIT=1 you can have a condition on the custom action of RUNIT=1 or some other variatyion based on the way you want it to work.